# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin jar file

Tags: java, sonarqube, maven-plugin, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1

While trying to run sonar scanner we are getting the below error because of jar `iiq-bin-7.jar`, this `.jar` file is in encrypted format so it is unable to extract. But I am trying to exclude this jar file, so sonar no need to consider this jar file. But it is not excluding.

Is there any way to exclude the jar file?

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project iiq:
>
> Can not create ClassLoader: Unable to open /var/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/****/iiq/iiq-bin/7.0p3/iiq-bin-7.jar: error in opening zip file -> [Help 1]

I tried to add

```
<sonar.exclusions>/var/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/***/iiq/iiq-bin/7.0p3</sonar.exclusions>`
```

but it didn’t work.

Comment: Which commands do you execute to compile your application (example `mvn compile`) and run sonar (example `mvn sonar:sonar`)?